# I have to evaluate an expression but the operators are stored in a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my code:

```
def interpret(value, commands, args):
    ans = 0
    valid = ['+','-','*']
    if set(commands).issubset(valid):
        for ope,arg in zip(commands,args):
            ans = eval(r'value ope arg')
            value = ans
        return print (ans)
    else :
        return print('-1')

def main():
    interpret(1, ['+'], [1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Have tried `eval(value+ope+arg`) but got error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Have also looked for other solutions like to use regular expression and then evaluating it but not able to evaluate the expression

Expected answer = 2

Comment: what do you think `eval(r'value ope arg')` is doing? BTW `eval` using eval is _dangerous_! You should probably try another way...

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some other languages, Python does not automatically convert numbers to strings when using the `+` operator to concatenate strings.  You have to do this conversion explicitly.

```
ans = eval(str(value)+ope+str(arg))
```

Note, however, that [using `eval` is generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Comment: Can you please recommend what can I use instead of eval?